# Django YearArchiveView with date in related model

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have this one-to-one relationship between my models:

```py
class Training(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(unique=True)


class Report(models.Model):
    training = models.OneToOneField(
        Training, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True
    )
```

and would like to have a yearly archive of `Report`:

```py
class ReportYearArchiveView(generic.YearArchiveView):
    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    date_field = "training_date"
```

However, I get the following error:

```
FieldError at /reports/2022/
Cannot resolve keyword 'training_date' into field. Choices are: ..., training, training_id
```

With `date_field = "training__date"` I get

```
FieldDoesNotExist at /reports/2022/
Report has no field named 'training__date'
```

and with `date_field = "training"` I get

```
TypeError at /reports/2022/
Field 'id' expected a number but got datetime.date(2022, 1, 1).
```

I also tried turning `Training.date` into a primary key and `date_field = "training"`. This was working, as long as there were only `Report`s within one year, otherwise there were problems with treating `Report.training` as `DateField`.

Any ideas?

Comment: **change :** 

    date_field = "training_date"

**to :** 

    date_field = "training"

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but doesn't work as `date` is just a unique field and it would try the auto generated key `training.id` instead. I added the information.

Comment: A workaround is overwriting `get_dated_queryset`, `get_date_list` and `get_dated_items`, but then I'd rather just add `year`, `previous_year` and `next_year` to the context, I guess ...